# Have a button click increment another field? [101, js, PDF Forms]

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, button, increment

I'm trying to code a calculation on a pdf form, in which the click of a button(`deducting.button`) would deduct from the `base.number` field and show the new value in another field `final.number`. The only way I thought of getting that without altering the `base.number` field was to create a hidden `deducted.number` field (starting at 0, increasing with clicks on the `button`) to, after that, subtract from `base`.
The code to `final.number` is not included because that's the easy part, and meant for the final.number form field.
I tried the following code after seeing somewhat similar cases that made some sense to me, but considering my inexperience with coding, 'sense' means very little. There's likely many functions and operations I don't know/ didn't know how to search properly.

Both corrections to the code and suggestions of better methods are appreciated.

```
var x=this.getField ("deducting.button");
var y=this.getField ("deducted.number");
var z=this.getField ("base.number");
y.value = 0;
x.onclick = function () {
if (y.value < z.value) {y.value += 1;}
else {y.value += -1;}
}
```

I saw many somewhat similar codes which included things like 'private int', 'function inc()', 'parseInt', '++', 'string' and/or 'addListener' along the process but couldn't quite get what they were doing, I followed the simplest I could find, yet quite certain I'm skipping a step or two...

The `deducted.number` field shows the starting 0, but clicking on the `deducting.button` changes nothing. (I'm pretty sure it is restarting to 0 everytime, if at all reacting to the click) What am I doing wrong?
btw, This code is added to the `deducted.number` field, mainly because I read that form codes altering values of other form values can cause errors on pdf script calculations. If it's not the case or there is a solution, I'm also interested.

Forgive if this is too similar to other questions here, but I've gone through quite many of them and nothing worked, so decided to bring my question with the "original code" I thought considering my own "effort".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a PDF form or an XFA form (created with LiveCycle Designer)?

Comment: PDF form created with foxit PhantomPDF, pretty similar to Adobe X.
As an update, I've been trying tens of different iterations with inc, listener, still no success. I'm definitely missing some essential on js language or the pdf editor's limitations...

Comment: Yes, you miss something essential of Acrobat JavaScript. There is no "onclick" property of a field object. In PDF you add the according code to the mouseUp event of the button.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to add the code to the incremented field rather than the button, worried some js error would apply because I read somewhere altering values not on the event field would likely incur errors. Nevermind that I guess :)
Thanks, by coding through the button it was a matter of 5 or 6 searches and my problem was solved. I will add the code as answer for the sake of completion.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: This code is for PDF form on foxit PhantomPDF 7.0, the interfaces, buttons, fields and such are created by its tools hence not included as code.

Coding from the ***button*** instead of the incremented field, I was able to figure it out, being for my original intent an actual decrement, reducing up to 0. Run a Javascript from the button:

```
var x = this.getField("base_value");
var y = this.getField("discounted_value");
if(isNaN(y.value))
y.value = x.value;
else
y.value += -1;
if (y.value < 0) {y.value=0;}
```

Hope this helps someone else who might need it.